# Reading qr code with Zxing .Net 0.14.0.1 is not working when taking photo with camera

Tags: c#, .net, qr-code, zxing

When reading a qr code that was generated via a qr code generator website and downloaded directly I am able to read the qr code with the following lines of code

```
 var reader = new BarcodeReader();
 reader.Options.TryHarder = true;
 reader.Options.PossibleFormats = new List<BarcodeFormat>();
 reader.Options.PossibleFormats.Add(BarcodeFormat.QR_CODE);
 var result = reader.Decode(new Bitmap(image));
```

This is working well for the following downloaded qr code

[image]

But it is not working for camera photos of the qr code like the following one

[image]

Even when I crop it it is not working

[image]

I have already tried downgrading to other versions as 0.14.0.1 and the other instructions from similar StackOverflow questions

I would appreciate your answer!

Comment: I even tried to crop the qr code to square size, but it kept on not recognizing the code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to downsize your qr code since the camera on you mobile may create photos that are so high in resolution that the library takes to long to process them and just timeouts.

Try downsizing them to 512*512 before you process them.

Comment: I also have to mark that it even works with full hd photos (1920x1080), but 4k is a resolution that is too high for the library to process.